# Как реализовать такой слайдер? (фото в приложении)

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

[image: Слайдер]
При верстке лендинга столкнулась с таким слайдером. Конкретно интересует, как реализовать перемещение левого и правого слайда в центр? Ранее с подобными задачами не сталкивалась. Буду благодарна, если подскажете библиотеку или примерно суть реализации. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Не совсем понял что нужно сделать. Возможно slick поможет http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: при нажатии на правую кнопку слайд переходит из уменьшенного состояния в центр, как бы эффект 3D

Comment: Библиотека - та какой-нибудь слайдер, [например](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/). А суть реализации - допустим, задать элементам слайдера абсолютное позиционирование (относительного самого слайдера), и просто перемещать их как Вам угодно. А там, стилями можно и увеличивать при перемещении.

Answer (score 3):

Пример с `slick-slider`

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  slidesToShow:3,
  centerMode:true,
  centerPadding:0,
  focusOnSelect:true
})
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
*:focus{
  outline:none;
}
.slide:before{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  min-height:100px;
  background:radial-gradient(circle at center,yellow,orange);
  opacity:.5;
  transform-origin:center;
  transform:scale(.6);
  transition:all .5s ease;
}
.slide.slick-center:before{
  opacity:1;
  transform:scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let sliderArr = {};
let current = 0;
let max;
for (let i = 1; i < document.getElementById("slider").children.length - 1; i++) {
  sliderArr[String(i)] = document.getElementById("slider").children[i];
  if (document.getElementById("slider").children[i].classList.contains("active")) {
    current = i;
  }
  max = i;
}
document.getElementsByClassName("arrowLeft")[0].onclick = function() {
  if (current > 1) {
    $(sliderArr[current]).animate({
      height: '100px',
      marginTop: '100px',
      width: '100px'
    });
    $(sliderArr[current - 1]).animate({
      height: '150px',
      marginTop: '75px',
      width: '150px'
    });
    current--;
  }
}

document.getElementsByClassName("arrowRight")[0].onclick = function() {
  if (current < max) {
    $(sliderArr[current]).animate({
      height: '100px',
      marginTop: '100px',
      width: '100px'
    });
    $(sliderArr[current + 1]).animate({
      height: '150px',
      marginTop: '75px',
      width: '150px'
    });
    current++;
  }
}
```

```css
#slider {
  float: left;
  width: 430px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none;
}

.arrow {
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 300px;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

.arrowLeft {
  float: left;
}

.arrowRight {
  float: right;
}

.slide {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #333;
  margin-top: 75px;
}

.slide1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px
}

.slide3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <div class="arrow arrowLeft">
    <</div>
      <img class="slide slide1">
      <img class="slide slide2 active">
      <img class="slide slide3">
      <div class="arrow arrowRight">></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Попробую

Comment: _Конкретно интересует, как реализовать перемещение левого и правого слайда в центр_ активный слайд должен быть в центре